# Module not found for framework dependency in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, dependencies, cocoapods

I have a project with multiple framework targets, that also have pods dependencies.

I have:

- No circular dependencies between targets
- Everything, including pods, is in Objective-C, no Swift at all.
- `use_frameworks!` in Podfile, so all pods are frameworks, not libraries.

Here is my structure:

- `TUSystemKit` depends on `TUModels` (which is a framework).
- `TUModels` depends on `Pods_TUModels` (generated by pods).
- `Pods_TUModels` depends on `JSONModel`
- `TUModels` is automatically linked with its own pod framework (which contains `JSONModel`).
- `TUSystemKit` has `TUModels` as target dependency.
- `TUSystemKit` is linked with `TUModels`.

Visually, the dependencies are like this:

`TUSystemKit` ➔ `TUModels` ➔ `Pods_TUModels` ➔ `JSONModel`

When I select `MyModels` as the build target in Xcode, build succeeds. However, when I select `TUSystemKit`, the build fails, saying that module `JSONModel` is not found *while building module* `TUSystemKit` (`TUUser` in screenshot belongs to `TUModels`):

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Obviously I shouldn't be explicitly linking against all the frameworks in the dependency tree. Why does `TUModels` build perfectly but `TUSystemKit` errs on *a module import inside a linked framework's code*? Do I need to change something with pods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of refactoring, I've managed to build my project. I can't tell what exactly was wrong as it took me literally a day to organize all the dependencies and frameworks and it kept failing at a different point, more than a 100 times, but here are some observations to lead to a successful build:

- All the public-facing classes are added as public headers to the target, and not to any other target.
- All the code (.m files) are in Compile Sources section of the target, and not in any other target.
- All the public facing classes' headers are included at umbrella header (a header with the exact same name with the framework)
- The application embeds all the custom frameworks (not the pods).
- All the files inside a framework target only `#import` required files within the same target or a file listed on any targets umbrella header that the framework has a dependency on.
- Obvious, redundant, but worth noting again: **no classes between frameworks should have circular dependencies** (e.g. ClassA in FrameworkA depends on ClassB in FrameworkB, while some class in FrameworkB depends on some class on FrameworkA). I had some, and created delegates. Do whatever pattern fits your design: IoT/dependency injection, notifications/publisher-subscriber etc. But do it: separate the concerns clearly.
- Try to avoid using same classes in multiple targets. Instead, have it in one target, and make the other target depend on the containing target, creating a dependency chain.

After refactoring many files and playing with project settings, I managed to build and run everything again. My previous setup had various number of combinations of the issues that I mentioned above, messing everything up. After cleaning all the bits and grouping code into functional, modular frameworks, I could build it.

Answer (score 0):

If you came here due to the **parse error -> module not found**,
in certain occasions you may be forced to add the path manually.
This is...

- go to **your project** at the top
- select your project **target**
- select **build settings**
- search the parameter **Framework Search Paths** under the title **Search Paths**
- add the one where yours is located. Example: (using cocoa pods) **$(SRCROOT)/Pods**
- indicate/set it to be **recursive**  (access to the option by double-clicking your previously added path)

The problem should have been resolved by the 3erd party lib with commands like **install / update / build** or similar but if it fails and you are stuck, this is an option in order to continue.

In the same tone, if you get an error from pods indicating that
**The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile** because the builder is unable to find files like **Podfile.lock**, then you may consider to go in the same direction adding some user-defined settings:

- select **build settings**
- press the '+' symbol, "Add User-Defined Setting".
- add this pair:

  - param= **PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH** value = **${SRCROOT}/.**
  - param = **PODS_ROOT** value = **${SRCROOT}/Pods**

Cheers